# Samsung Galaxy Phone is not recognized on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, connection, driver, samsung-mobile, galaxy

My Samsung phone was not recognized by Android Studio on windows 7. I repaired it by installing the Samung Driver here: 
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

I tested with my Galaxy S2 and the Samsung S7560 and it works now

Comment: no it's an answer that I think it can help people ;)

Comment: it did help. in addition i had to change the usb-pc connection on my samsung from media device (mtp) to camera (ptp)

Comment: @matthias: my samsung seems to work fine in (mtp) mode rather than (ptp) mode.  The key for me was enabling developer mode and then developer usb debugging as suggested by Edward Islam below

Comment: different answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553097/cannot-update-samsung-galaxy-s7-driver-to-android-driver-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

I solved in following way:

```
    Go to Settings->Developer options-> On top of the screen, turn on the button.
```

Now goto bottom on the debugging section.

```
    Now turn on USB debugging option
```

It will ask some questions if you want to allow the PC to this device, press allow all time!

Answer (score 2):

Here are few steps if your android phone create problem next time

1. Make sure developer mode is enable
2. Make sure Android studio is up to date
3. Make sure Android Phone is also up to date

Comment: the answer is not so relevant, since its a manufacturer specific question(and questioner says himself question as a solution too).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when connecting a SM-T113 to a Windows 7 PC. The problem was solved by installing Smart Switch.

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy J7(2016) same problem solved 
when i go to software update section on phone.
asked me to allow debug mode from this computer . Checked always trust this computer. and OK
Note : Usb mode PTP