# Cannot update Samsung Galaxy S7 driver to android driver on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to develop an app using Android Studio 3.3.2 on a Windows 7 desktop and a Samsung Galaxy S7 phone. On the phone, I enabled developer options and USB debugging.
But when I connect the phone, it is seen as MTP and not Android.

[image: device manager:]

Since the Google usb driver is only for Pixel/Nexus, I downloaded the [Samsung driver](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows)
When I try to update it by uninstalling the Samsung S7 driver, then when I reconnect my phone, it automatically installs the Samsung S7 driver.
When I try instead to update the MTP driver, I get an error.

[image: cannot update MTP driver]

When I try to *install from disk* I get this error
[image: install from disk error]

I have not seen this before using other computers/devices. 
I am at a loss...

Comment: This is not off-topic as it has been asked several times before here. It is part of android development. Also the method for updating the Samsung driver is different than the method for updating the Google driver. Developers are often stuck at this step. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056544/samsung-galaxy-phone-is-not-recognized-on-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524254/cant-connect-to-samsung-galaxy-tab-s-with-android-studio-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". My question fits this criterion. I am connecting my android phone to Android Studio to develop my app.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I found that the 'driver' from Samsung is actually a zipped folder containing an executable. So I had to double-click and run to install it. Restart my PC.
2. Turn developer options off and then on again. On the phone you will see a dialog asking for USB permissions. Okay'ed it.